# Не запускается Вегас на Линукс

Tags: linux, ubuntu, видео, wine

Здравствуйте.
У меня Ubuntu 16.04.
Хочу установить себе Sony Vegas pro 13 через PlayOnLinux.
Установка проходит в штатном режиме. 
Как исправить и что делать?
При запуске приложения происходит ошибка, при отладке пишет вот что:
Первая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вторая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Третья:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой новой версии Wine